# GWT UiBinder and Image Sprites

Tags: gwt, sprite, uibinder, clientbundle

I'm having trouble getting CSS image sprites to appear in GWT UiBinder. I did review [how do i use image sprites in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535094/how-do-i-use-image-sprites-in-gwt), but found I was already doing what was suggested.

I have a `ui.xml`, `ClientBundle` interface with a `CssBundle` nested interface, and a css file.

ui.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:with field="resources"
    type="edu.wts.upholdingthetruth.poweroftheword.client.resources.POWResources" />

    <g:FlowPanel width="100%" styleName="{resources.sprites.underMenuGlow}" />
</ui:UiBinder>
```

ClientBundle:

```
public interface POWResources extends ClientBundle {
    public static final POWResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(POWResources.class);

    @Source("site1/undertopglow.png")
    ImageResource underTopGlow();

    @Source("sprites.css")
    public Sprites sprites();

    public interface Sprites extends CssResource {

            String underMenuGlow();
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

sprites.css:

```
@sprite .underMenuGlow {gwt-image: "underTopGlow"}
```

So, I compile my app (which does not complain), and in the browser, my image is missing. When I review the page in Chrome's Developer Tools, I see the corresponding div references the obfuscated css class, but I was not able to find that class defined anywhere.

I was, on the other hand, able to display the image using `<g:Image resource="{resources.underTopGlow}" />`.

Is there a step I am missing to get images to display via css sprites like this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to call `ensureInjected()` on your `CssResource` somewhere in your code; either:

```
POWResources.INSTANCE.sprites().ensureInjected();
```

or

```
@UiField POWResources resources;
…
resources.sprites().ensureInjected();
```

Alternatively, if you don't share the styles/images with other code, you can replace your ClientBundle with the implicit one that UiBinder creates from `ui:style` and `ui:image` (and UiBinder will then take care of calling `ensureInjected` for you):

```
<ui:style>
  @sprite .underMenuGlow {gwt-image: "underTopGlow"}
</ui:style>
<ui:image field="underTopGlow" src="site1/undertopglow.png" />
…
<span class="{style.underMenuGlow}">foo</span>
```