# How to add an icon near a GWT menuItem (UI binder code prefered)?

Tags: gwt, menuitem, css-sprites

Maybe it is very simple, but I did found the solution. I just want to have an image (as simple as a "black triangle") near a menu item. If it is possible with UI binder, it would be better. I just know there is the .setHTML(html) function... I would like an example, where the image to load (the "black triangle") is a sprite...

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use sprites, you can basically adapt the example from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4548524/291741

Then you can set the sprite on a simple `<div>`:

```xml
<g:MenuBar>
  <g:MenuItem>Tools
    <g:MenuBar vertical="true">
      <g:MenuItem>
        <div class="{myResources.myCss.myBackground}"/> Triangle
      </g:MenuItem>
    </g:MenuBar>
  </g:MenuItem>
</g:MenuBar>
```

<strike>But wouldn't it be easier to use a `<g:Image resource="..."/>` instead?</strike> (no, see comment)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the answer but I can not use the <g:Image resource="..."/> instead of the div (inside menuItem because I have an error saying : "Not allowed in an HTML context...". I think you have understood my case, but to illustrate it I want to do these 'dropdown menu button': http://code.shrapp.nl/google-plus-ui-buttons/demo.html